# ruby osascript on windows?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am trying to use a Ruby script which I found - but it fails, and I think the problem is that it uses *osascript* to run a small javascript-script, and I am suspecting that this makes the Ruby program Mac specific, is this correct/ If so, is there any easy windows equivalent for a port?

There are so many windows interpreters for languages, seems odd if none for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

osascript is not javascript but instead AppleScript — I don't know of any interpreter for Windows.